# How to identify straight edges on raster

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, watershed, flood

I have water surface elevation rasters that I would like to QC for "inorganic shapes" like the screenshot below that are a result of modeling errors. What would be the best method to identify cells containing values in a straight line with NoData values adjacent to them?

[image]

Comment: Using what software?

Comment: Apologies, ArcGIS Pro

Answer (score 1):

I might try...

1. [Reclassify](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/reclassify.htm) your raster such that NoData = NoData and all other values = 1
2. Convert the [raster to to a polygon](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/raster-to-polygon.htm) with non-simplified output.
3. [Convert the resulting polygon to lines](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/polygon-to-line.htm).
4. [Split the resulting lines at the vertices](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/split-line-at-vertices.htm).  Sending the output to a file geodatabase feature class will result in a file that includes the length of the resulting line.
5. Determine for yourself how long of a line satisfies your personal criteria for what defines a 'a straight line with NoData values adjacent to them'.
6. Apply your definition in a [select by attribute](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/select-layer-by-attribute.htm) to your lines to identify those areas of interest to you.
7. Attribute the selection for query or symbology or export to a new feature class if you want or need to.